# HTTP Auth not working

Tags: php, http

I'm passing username and password like this `http://user:pass@localhost/try`.

and in my index.php I have this code.

```
    $username = null;
    $password = null;


    if (isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
        $username = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
        $password = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'];

    } elseif (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'])) {

            if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']),'basic')===0)
              list($username,$password) = explode(':',base64_decode(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'], 6)));

    }

    if (is_null($username)) {

        header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
        header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
        echo 'Text to send if user hits Cancel button';

        die();

    } else {
        echo "<p>Hello {$username}.</p>";
        echo "<p>You entered {$password} as your password.</p>";
    }
```

But it always go to `is_null($username)`.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong.
Thanks.

Comment: You should use some simple debugging statements to make sure that the branches in logic that you assume are being taken as a result of variables being defined, are, in fact, being taken.

Answer (score 0):

```
} elseif (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'])) {

        if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']),'basic')===0)
          list($username,$password) = explode(':',base64_decode(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'], 6)));

}
```

should be

```
} elseif (isset($_SERVER['Authorization'])) {

        if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['Authorization']),'basic')===0)
          list($username,$password) = explode(':',base64_decode(substr($_SERVER['Authorization'], 6)));

}
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication#Basic_authentication_scheme

Comment: Thanks @Ari, I tried your code but it still not working.